# Passwordless SSH error while Installing the Big Insight

Tags: linux, ssh, biginsights

I am getting below error while installing BigInsight in my Linux machine (RedHat 6.6). Kindly help me how to resolve this.

[ERROR] Prerequisite check - Failed to use given credentials to access nodes.Either provide root password during add node or make sure BI admin user exists on new nodes and passwordless ssh is setup from management node to new nodes that are being added. Please revisit Secure Shell page from installer UI or SSH section in response file to make sure all prerequisites are satisfied, then re-run the command.

Comment: can you provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following as root on the server and rerun

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa  ( leave blanks at all prompts )
cat /root/.ssh/*.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

then try root@localhost , this should not ask you for a password.